# Can't access object on main thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, thread-synchronization

So my application does as follows:

Main Thread:

1. Create new object1, which starts Thread1 in its constructor.
2. Instantiate object2, that contains a Vector3D and a AxisAngleRotation3D (among other things)
3. Do things
4. Thread1 tries to access object2.Position (Vector3D) and object2.Orientation (AxisAngleRotation3D). Position is OK, Orientation.Angle throws 'System.InvalidOperationException' saying "Calling thread cannot access the object because another thread owns it".

Both properties are created in the main thread, and it's only the AxisAngleRotation3D.Angle, Axis and InternalQuaternion that give the error. Debugging, I can confirm that the AxisAngleRotation3D object is created in the MainThread, and can't find any place on my code where it's accessed again, I've commented the only line where it's changed, so the only thing it does is be instantiated.

I'm totally lost here. Shouldn't I be able to access objects created in the parent thread? It works for other threads that I create similarly.

Is there any way I can see which thread owns the object that is throwing the exception, or debug when the AxisAngleRotation3D properties are being changed outside my own code?

I open the threads with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Thanks

Comment: [AxisAngleRotation3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.axisanglerotation3d(v=vs.110).aspx) derives from the [DispatcherObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject(v=vs.110).aspx) class. _Only the thread that the Dispatcher was created on may access the DispatcherObject directly. To access a DispatcherObject from a thread other than the thread the DispatcherObject was created on, call Invoke or BeginInvoke on the Dispatcher the DispatcherObject is associated with_

Comment: AxisAngleRotation3D also derives from Freezable.  If you `Freeze()` the object you can read it's properties on any class--but you won't be able to change any of its values any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks like it's already stated:

- Objects created on main thread (Thread 0)
- Tried to access object from Thread 1: Threw InvalidOperationException

The bottom line is that if you need cross thread access to UI objects you have a couple options:

- If the object is [`Freezable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable(v=vs.110).aspx) and you aren't going to change it's values you can freeze it.  (Vectors and Rotations are Freezable)
- Otherwise you can use the dependency object's dispatcher to access the values

**Freezing Objects**

```
if(freezable.CanFreeze)
{
    freezable.Freeze();
}
```

At this point you can read the objects on any thread--but you can't edit them again.  You can get an unfrozen copy of the class by calling the `Clone()` method and manipulate that, but you can't change values on the frozen object.

**Using the Dispatcher**

Freezable objects are also `DependencyObjects` so this works for anything in the UI layer:

```
var myAngle = myRotation.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() 
    ? myRotation.Orientation.Angle
    : (double)myRotation.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => myRotation.Orientation.Angle);
```

Of course, if the thread you are on is the UI thread (`Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == true`) then you don't need to worry about accessing the property.  If it is any other thread (`Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false`), then you have to pause this thread, queue work on the dispatcher and return when it is done.

Comment: .NET 4+ and WPF inparticular has constructs that  make `Invoke` unnecessary. The easiest would be to use `async/await` methods but the WPF/MVVM way would be to avoid modifying the UI *completely*, by binding UI elements to ViewModel properties and modifying the VM properties

Comment: Well, I've decided to simplify things for the moment and put aside some of the threads, it kind of defeats the purpose and adds a lot of complications if I have to delegate execution to the main thread all the time. I was trying to parallelize data getting and processing, but I will look into it again later, there's more pressing matters right now. 
Thanks for the answers anyway, I missed the fact that AxisAngleRotation3D derives from DispatcherObject and can only be accessed from owner thread. Why is this not permitted in these classes and not others escapes me, though.

Comment: @mikepa88, It has everything to do with the measure/layout/render cycle for XAML based classes.  When a panel is trying to determine where to place an element, it needs to make sure that the values won't change while the calculation is happening.  `async/await` is very useful for doing background work (.NET 4.5 and up).  When you come back from the background work you resume on the UI thread so you can do updates safely.  Although you still have to copy UI properties you want to calculate from and pass them to the task doing the work.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch These part of the code is entirely separated from the UI and XAML based classes, it's a bunch of background processes that are constantly receiving data and updating and creating objects as part of the application logic, which then the ViewModel will expose for the views. I just needed to be able to create an object in a thread and change it in a child thread, allowing to parellelize different processes. obviously taking care of properly locking access. I will find another way. Thanks for the info. I will definitely look into async/await